# HTML to multiple Excel worksheets using python

Tags: python, html, xml, django, excel

I have big xml file and I have to convert it to PDF and to Excel. First of all I've used xslt transformation and build html file with styles and formatting. There is no problem with PDF, I've used http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/ and it did what I need.
For Excel converting I've used Django HttpResponse with additional arguments:

```
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'
```

and I got Excel file with proper styles and formatting. But there is only one worksheet in this Excel file, though I need multiple worksheets (23 overall). It seems to me that there is no way to build Excel file with multiple worksheets from html.

I have also looked at http://www.python-excel.org/ but they don't really help me, because I would have to build the whole file and there is no way of using existing html file.

I have thought about VBA script that would split my one worksheet Excel file into multiple worksheets, but I don't really like this solution.

Are there any suggestions what I can do? I really don't want to build Excel file from the very beginning using xlrd and xlwt libraries. 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: You are happy with the output from Django HttpResponse except it creates a single worksheet.  Splitting one worksheet into twenty three with VBA would not normally be a difficult task so what don't you like about that solution?

Comment: If xslt gives you a correct xlsx file than there should be a way to split it the same way that Excel does. If you are getting a html which is understandable by Excel... I'd also try to see how does Excel itself manage multi-sheet documents while exporting to HTML. That should give a glue.

Comment: @TonyDallimore I don't like VBA solution because I should first save excel file, then open it and run VBA script. And I have a lot of files to repeat these steps, so I'm looking for some automatic solution.

Comment: @ilvar I have exported excel multisheet file into html, as far as I understand excel manage every sheet as a single html file. Though I have one html file and no possibility to split it and store somewhere.

Comment: I can see that a solution that converts one html file into multiple Excel worksheets in a single go would be the best.  But no such solution may be available.  A macro in one Excel workbook can open other workbooks and process their data so you do not have to handle each workbook individually.

Comment: BTW you can write a small utility to read table from HTML, process it cell-by-cell and output XLS using xlwt. If table formatting isn't very complex, this shouldn't be lots of code.